# Probable memory leak in spring MVC and Jasper for my report

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, jasper-reports

I have integrated Spring MVC 4 and Jasper 6.4.3 and it's successfully generating PDF reports but I am getting some probable memory leak problem in Tomcat console.

Here's the problem:

> SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>       [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@f6d3223]) and a value of type [org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap] (value [{WebappClassLoader
>         context: 
>         delegate: false
>       ----------> Parent Classloader:
>       java.net.URLClassLoader@5a07e868
>       =com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLGrammarPoolImpl@5b758d75}])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

I am using spring `JasperReportsMultiFormatView` which is declared in japser-view.xml file where I have declared my report and subreport datasource and its location.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doSalesMultiReport(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("type") String type,ModelAndView modelAndView, ModelMap model) {
    List<StationReportBean> items = new ArrayList<StationReportBean>();
    StationReportBean item4 = new StationReportBean();
    item4.setId(1);
    item4.setReportType("Hourly");
    item4.setStationName("Delhi");
    item4.setDeviceId(1);
    items.add(item4);
    List<DeviceReportBean> beans = new ArrayList<DeviceReportBean>();
    DeviceReportBean bean1=new DeviceReportBean();
    bean1.setId(1);
    bean1.setHours("00:00-01:00");
    bean1.setVoltageFirstPhase(1.1);
    bean1.setVoltageSecondPhase(1.2);
    bean1.setVoltageThirdPhase(1.3);
    bean1.setVoltageAvg(1.4);
    bean1.setCurrentFirstPhase(5.6);
    bean1.setCurrentSecondPhase(7.8);
    bean1.setCurrentThirdPhase(9.3);
    bean1.setCurrentAvg(1.1);
    bean1.setLoadFirstPhase(75.6);
    bean1.setLoadSecondPhase(7.98);
    bean1.setLoadThirdPhase(91.3);
    bean1.setLoadAvg(1.81);
    bean1.setPowerFactorFirstPhase(54.6);
    bean1.setPowerFactorSecondPhase(7.98);
    bean1.setPowerFactorThirdPhase(97.3);
    bean1.setPowerFactorAvg(11.11);
    bean1.setNetRunHour(1.0);
    bean1.setNetWattHour(2.0);
    beans.add(bean1);
    JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(items);
    JRDataSource  subDatasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beans);
    model.addAttribute("Datasource", datasource);
    model.addAttribute("JasperCustomSubReportDatasource", subDatasource);
    try {
        BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(request.getServletContext().getResource("/assets/img/favicon.png"));//when image is in webcontent

        model.addAttribute("logo", image );
    } catch (IOException e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    model.addAttribute("format", type);
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("multiReport", model);
    return modelAndView;
 }
```

This error is slowing down my development environment.

What is making it go wrong?

Comment: Looks like you need to use profiler

Comment: Thanks Alex for your quick reply.Can you guide me towards a free profiler and how to detect the issue in profiler?